# Enumerate vertices of convex hull defined by set of linear programming problems

Tags: linear-programming, convex-hulls

Consider the linear programming problem:
\begin{align*}
\text{maximize } & z \\
\text{where } & z = \mathbf{c} \cdot \mathbf{x}\\ 
\text{subject to } & \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}\\
\text{and } & \mathbf{x} \geq 0
\end{align*}

The vector $\mathbf{b}$ is now allowed to vary, keeping $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{A}$ constant. The set of maximal values of $z$ as a function of $\mathbf{b}$ defines a concave hull. Is there a method to efficiently enumerate the vertices of this hull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're taking the set $S$ of points
$(b,z) \in \mathbb R^{m+1}$ where $z$ is the maximal value of the linear
programming problem, over all $b$ for which the problem is feasible.
Note that if $x$ is a feasible solution for $b$ and $x'$ is a feasible solution for
$b'$, and $0 \le \lambda \le 1$, then $\lambda x + (1-\lambda) x'$ is 
feasible for $\lambda b + (1-\lambda) b'$, and of course
$c \cdot(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) x') = \lambda (c \cdot x) + (1-\lambda) (c \cdot x')$, so $z$ is a concave function of $b$.  I'll assume the feasible set is nonempty and the problem is dual-feasible, so not unbounded.

One may consider basic solutions corresponding to a nonsingular submatrix $B$ of the augmented matrix, where the basic variable values are $B^{-1} b$, the nonbasic variable values are all $0$, and the objective value is $c_B B^{-1} b$.  This is feasible in the convex set where all basic decision variable values are nonnegative and all basic slack variable values are $0$.  The objective value is always equal to the value in one of the basic solutions.  Each extreme point of $S$ should be an extreme point of the region of feasibility of one of the basic solutions.